# Test-Path - Variable Part of FileName - Variable doesn't get substituted

Tags: powershell

SourceFile.txt has the below

```
<somepath>\filename_$tminus1.csv
```

The below is the script I've written.

```
$date = [DateTime]::ParseExact("21-Aug-18", "dd-MMM-yy", $null)

if ($date.DayOfWeek -eq "Monday") {
    $tminus1 = $date.AddDays(-3).ToString('yyyyMMdd')
    $tminus2 = $date.AddDays(-4).ToString('yyyyMMdd')
    Write-Host "Date vaulues set for Monday"
} else {
    $tminus1 = $date.AddDays(-1).ToString('yyyyMMdd')
    $tminus2 = $date.AddDays(-2).ToString('yyyyMMdd')
    Write-Host "Date vaulues set for Non-Monday"
}

$files = Get-Content -Path $PSScriptRoot\SourceFile.txt

foreach ($file in $files) {
    Convert-Path $file

    if (-not (Test-Path $file)) {
        echo ""
        Write-Host "$file doesn't exist"
    } else {
        echo ""
        Write-Host "$file exists"
    }
}
```

The `Test-Path` cmdlet doesn't get the variable value substituted while looking for the file. It prints the below.

```
<somepath>\filename_$tminus1.csv doesn't exist
```

I expect the `$tminus1` value gets substituted as 20180823 so that the else part prints the below.

```
<somepath>\filename_$tminus1.csv exists
```

Comment: See [about_Quoting_Rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-6)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is when you pull the text in from your CSV it is treated as a literal, as if it as was a single quoted string. You can force PowerShell to re-evalueate the string like so:

```
$file = $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($file)
```

Or an alternative method would be to change the text in the CSV to this:

```
<somepath>\filename_{0}.csv
```

You can then use the format string to apply the variable like so:

```
$file = $file -f $tminus1
```

Answer (score 0):

When you read strings from a file, PowerShell does not perform the normal interpolation it does for strings in your code.  One way to get around this is to use `Invoke-Expression`.

Say you have a file (`paths.txt`) with these paths in it:

```
C:\Data\$dir1
C:\Data\$dir2
```

You can get the real paths like this:

```
$dir1 = "Directory1"
$dir2 = "Directory2"

Get-Content paths.txt |
    ForEach-Object {
        Invoke-Expression """$_"""
    }
```

This will output:

```
C:\Data\Directory1
C:\Data\Directory2
```

Obviously, you can capture these to a variable, send them along the pipeline, etc, instead of just outputting them.